# Where is sys/msg.h located?

Tags: c, linux, ipc

I'm writing some C/C++ programs that uses the header . I want to look into this header, but I don't find him on my Ubuntu system(version 14.04).

Where is the file located?

Comment: `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/msg.h` for `x86_64`...

Comment: [locate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix)) function's for pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ locate msg.h

....
/usr/include/sys/msg.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/msg.h
....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i found it now